# Dismissible or Swipe Action DataRow inside DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to implement dismissible or swipe action for DataRow inside DataTable. So far I can only find such feature mostly used/shown on Lists. The reason I'm using DataTable is because I'd like to show horizontal scroll available data list and show as in data table style. Here is my code and I'd much appreciate if there's any pointer available.

```
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Date')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Customer')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Amount'), numeric: true),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Remark')),
            ],
            rows: snapshot.data
                .map(
                  (item) => DataRow(
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(
                          DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(item.date))),
                      DataCell(Text(item.customerName)),
                      DataCell(
                          Text(NumberFormat().format(item.amount))),
                      DataCell(Text(item.remark)),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

Thanks!

Comment: hmm you could achieve that when you put the row content in a button or gesture detection. not sure if there is a better solution

Comment: @Neli. The problem is the property "rows" only accept "DataRow". I cannot even wrap with Gesturedetector. :(

Comment: Was thinking of implementing a same solution. Had any luck finding the solution @RyanPaing??

Comment: @JalakamKiran Nope. Not yet. I skipped that feature for now. Please do let me know if you come across some. Thanks!

Comment: Any success on this issue? I am facing the same issue and I now had multiple times the same problem with this data table. No having any access to the "row" widget (only to the DataRow) seems like a big disadvantage. I might just go with another widget and no longer use the data table...

Comment: @xooback Haven't tried it yet. I skipped that feature and implemented using icons/buttons. Would be nice if we can have it for Tables.